# Why can't one see the edit summary of their deleted post?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, revisions-list

I recently noted that one is not allowed to see the edit history of their post if it is deleted. e.g. when I click on the edit summary [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/82952/2) of [this<sup>1</sup>](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/82952/31782) self-deleted post of mine I meet the 404 error. The same is true for the community deleted posts. But the mods and high rep users can see them. Is it a bug or a feature added for some purpose?

- If it is a feature than what is its benefit? Why shouldn't the low-rep users see their own posts' history?
- Is it a bug?

---

1<sub>Please do not ask me about why I deleted that post. I posted that when I was new. Since it is a bad answer I deleted it.</sub>

Comment: It seems that Latex doesn't work here. Would anyone correct the subscript in my post. $^1$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mat: Thanks for the editing [this<sup>1</sup>], seems like it doesn't work in the comment.

Comment: It appears that it is a bug because when I click on the _edit_ of the old version I can see the whole old text. Means the developers have allowed one to see the old version of his/her deleted post.

Comment: Dear community-moderator, this post may show zero activity for a long time. Please do not clean this out of the city.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *when* this happened, but it seems to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). I have a [self-deleted question on Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/345040/77072) and I'm able to see both the [revision history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjMWk.png) and the [individual revisions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F412C.png).

Answer (score 1):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) or [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This was either a bug, or it has been changed purposefully; I don't know about how it was *supposed* to work back when this was written, but **currently, users can see the edit histories of their own posts.**

On Sci-Fi, I have less than 10,000 reputation. I went to [a deleted post of mine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/215778/102999) and clicked on the revision history. I can see it:

[image: The revision history is visible to me]